# pygame.key.get_pressed() is not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to take continuous input from the user and do things based on that. I'm trying to use the key.get_pressed() function in the pygame module. But, I can't get it to work. I've looked at all the other similar questions but none of those solutions seem to work.

```
import pygame, RCcarFunctions, time
pygame.init()
keypressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
try:
  while True:
    if keypressed == "pygame.K_w":
      RCcarFunctions.forward()
    elif keypressed  == "pygame.K_a":
      RCcarFunctions.spinleft()
    elif keypressed == "pygame.K_s":
      RCcarFunctions.reverse()
    elif keypressed == "pygame.K_d":
      RCcarFunctions.spinright()
    elif keypressed == "pygame.K_ESCAPE":
      RCcarFunctions.stop()
    pygame.event.pump()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  RCcarFunctions.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Use an event que and poll the state of the required keys. If they are 'down' toggle a bool to True, if they are 'up' toggle the bool to false(separate bool for each key). Then outside the event que check the state of each bool, based on that do whatever.

The main problem I was having was that I didn't have a display initialized, I was completely unaware that you have to have a display initialized for pygame to work. After initializing a display, I got it to work.

```
pygame.init()
size = (640,480)
pygame.display.setmode((640,480))
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        forward = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        left = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
        reverse = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
        right = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        forward = False
      elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        left = False
      elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
        reverse = False
      elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
        right = False
  if forward & right:
    RCcarFunctions.right()
  elif forward & left:
    RCcarFunctions.left()
  elif forward:
    RCcarFunctions.forward()
  elif left:
    RCcarFunctions.spinleft()
  elif reverse:
    RCcarFunctions.reverse()
  elif right:
    RCcarFunctions.spinright()
  else:
    RCcarFunctions.stop()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print ("\ncleaning up")
  RCcarFunctions.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the code to `get_pressed()` inside the loop.

Also you need to verify what it returns: 
 a list of bools indexed by the constants.
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed

```
import pygame, RCcarFunctions, time
pygame.init()

try:
  while True:
    #get_pressed() returns a list of bools ? 
    keypressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keypressed[pygame.K_w]:
      RCcarFunctions.forward()
    elif keypressed[pygame.K_a]:
      RCcarFunctions.spinleft()
    elif keypressed[pygame.K_s]:
      RCcarFunctions.reverse()
    elif keypressed[pygame.K_d]:
      RCcarFunctions.spinright()
    elif keypressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
      RCcarFunctions.stop()
    pygame.event.pump()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  RCcarFunctions.cleanup()
```

Comment: How do I verify that it returns a list of booleans? And why would it return anything else?

Comment: @Fazer you should read the documentation about the function.I included a link to it. Below the description is a link to examples to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `pygame.key.get_pressed()` call inside your `while True` loop as follows:

```
import pygame, RCcarFunctions, time
pygame.init()
try:
  while True:
    keypressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keypressed == "pygame.K_w":
      RCcarFunctions.forward()
    elif keypressed  == "pygame.K_a":
      RCcarFunctions.spinleft()
    elif keypressed == "pygame.K_s":
      RCcarFunctions.reverse()
    elif keypressed == "pygame.K_d":
      RCcarFunctions.spinright()
    elif keypressed == "pygame.K_ESCAPE":
      RCcarFunctions.stop()
    pygame.event.pump()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  RCcarFunctions.cleanup()
```

Comment: It didn't work. I know that the issue's not with my RCcarFunctions library because each of those functions work fine when called individually.